# Can I use Ninject to instantiate singleton services that nothing depends on?

Tags: c#, singleton, ninject

I have some services in my asp.net mvc application that listen for AMQP messages and invoke methods.

No controllers depend on this, so it won't get instantiated on its own.

I could instantiate it manually, explicitly providing its dependencies with `kernel.Get` but it feels like I shouldn't have to do that.

Can I make Ninject instantiate classes in singleton scope *eagerly* even when nothing else depends on it?

Comment: When bootstrapping (application start) just call your singleton once and it'll be created.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Yes but to do that I will have to explicitly provide all of my singleton's dependencies. All of its dependencies are bound in Ninject, which makes it very easy to Ninject to build it on its own.

Comment: If you got a property with injection (or constructor) it'll be instantiated automatically and you won't have to resolve the dependencies by yourself.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I don't understand how I would do that?

Comment: Place the `Inject` attribute above the property like this: `[Inject]`. Or pass the class (or related interface) into a constructor which you call straight after the bootstrapping.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst The point I'm trying to make is that *nothing depends on this class.* It is a standalone service. So I could add it as a property or constructor parameter to a controller but then that reference would be unused... it would only exist to first Ninject to instantiate the class... seemed wrong to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have ninject instantiate stuff in case you don't ask it to instantiate something yourself.
The simple way is to ask ninject to instantiate things at composition root:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
kernel.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()); // loads all modules in assemlby
//...
// resolution root completely configured

kernel.Resolve<IFooSingleton>();
kernel.Resolve<IBarSIngleton>();
```

There is one alternative, actually, which is not the same, but can be used to achieve a similar effect. It requires that there is at least one single other service instantiated soon enough: [Ninject.Extensions.DependencyCreation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.dependencycreation).
It works like this:

```
kernel.Bind<string>().ToConstant("hello");

kernel.Bind<ISingletonDependency>().To<SingletonDependency>()
    .InSingletonScope();
kernel.DefineDependency<string, ISingletonDependency>();

kernel.Get<string>();
// when asking for a string for the first time
// ISingletonDependency will be instantiated.
// of course you can use any other type instead of string
```

### Why

Ninject is unlike some other containers (for example Autofac) not "built" in stages. There's no concept of first creating the bindings, and then creating the kernel to use them. The following is perfectly legal:

```
kernel.Bind<IFoo>()...
kernel.Get<IFoo>()...
kernel.Bind<IBar>()...
kernel.Get<IBar>()...
```

so ninject can't possibly know *when* you want the singletons to be instantiated. With autofac [it's clear and easy](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html):

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

containerBuilder
    .RegisterType<Foo>()
    .AutoActivate();

var container = containerBuilder.Build(); // now
```

Comment: Is `kernel.Resolve<IFooSingleton>();` like this actually having any effect, since instances are only resolved upon iteration?

Comment: @JanGassen I don't really understand your question. `kernel.Resolve<...>` , with a singleton, it creates an instance the first time and returns the "old" instance for every further call. So the effect of the first call is instanciation + caching (making sure it doesn't get garbage-collected until the kernel is disposed).

Comment: I think `IResolutionRoot.Resolve` returns a lazily evaluated enumerable, meaning iterated items will only be created on iteration. If this is true, just calling `Resolve` might _not_ create an instance. By looking at the code, this might however depend on the configured bindings.

Comment: @JanGassen some Resolve overloads might. But `Resolve<IFooSingleton>` does not return an `IEnumerable`. It returns an `IFooSingleton`. No lazy evaluation possible.

Answer (score 4):

Coming from Guice in Java, I've sorely missed the pattern of eager singletons. They are useful in scenarios where for example modules act as plugins. If you imagine that a service is assembled from modules that are specified in a configuration, you could see a problem of then also trying to specify what this module needs to be auto-instantiated when the application is started.

For me the module is where the composition of the application is defined and separating eager singletons into another place in the code feels more clunky and less intuitive.

Anyway, I've been able to very easily implement this as a layer on top of Ninject, here's the code:

```
public static class EagerSingleton
{
    public static IBindingNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> AsEagerSingleton<T>(this IBindingInSyntax<T> binding)
    {
        var r = binding.InSingletonScope();

        binding.Kernel.Bind<IEagerSingleton>().To<EagerSingleton<T>>().InSingletonScope();

        return r;
    }
}

public interface IEagerSingleton { }

public class EagerSingleton<TComponent> : IEagerSingleton
{
    public EagerSingleton(TComponent component)
    {
        // do nothing. DI created the component for this constructor.
    }
}

public class EagerSingletonSvc
{
    public EagerSingletonSvc(IEagerSingleton[] singletons)
    {
        // do nothing. DI created all the singletons for this constructor.
    }
}
```

After you've created your kernel, add a single line:

```
kernel.Get<EagerSingletonSvc>(); // activate all eager singletons
```

You use it in a module like this:

```
Bind<UnhandledExceptionHandlerSvc>().ToSelf().AsEagerSingleton();
```

Comment: This is just a fancy way of calling `kernel.Get` for each eager singleton, which hides the call to `kernel.Get`.

Comment: @FlorianWinter correct! In Ninject the places where you declare everything about your dependencies, and where you create the container and use it can be very separate, so this is a way to declare the need for eager creation at the former stage with a generic mechanism that executes on those declarations at the latter.